# Find the values of $a,b,c$ of the complex function $f(x)= (ax+b)/(x+c)$

Tags: complex-numbers

The task is to find the values of $a$,$b$, and $c$ of the complex function $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{x+c}$  where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$.

It is given that $f(2i)=-2i$ and $f(1+3i)=1-3i$.

I tried to make an equation $f(2i) + 1-i = f(1+3i)$. However this is very hard to solve.

I think I have to find another way, something with conjugates as the function gives the conjugate.

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You have the right idea. Since $a,b,c$ are real, $f(-2i)=2i$ and $f(1-3i)=1+3i$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**
$$-2i = f(2i) = \frac{2ia + b}{2i+c}$$
Assuming $c \neq -2i$, we have $2ia + b = -2i(2i+c) = 4-2ic$, hence $b = 4$ and $a=-c$. Can you plug this into the definition of $f$ and use the second constraint to find the last remaining parameter?